# How can I reference a specific type of sibling XML node from the predicate in an XPath expression?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm working on an XSLT stylesheet to transform a simple HTML document to a Unix man page.  I have a situation where I want to match a text node only if it immediately follows a `<ul>` sibling node in the parent.  For example, here's what I want to transform:

```
<html>
<body>

<dl>

  <dt>This is the first term to define.</dt>
  <dd>This is the first definition.</dd>

  <dt>This is the second term to define.</dt>
  <dd>This is the second definition, with a list in the middle:
  <ul>
    <li>This is the first item in the list.</li>
    <li>This is the second item in the list.</li>
  </ul>
  And now there's a sentence after the list.</dd>

</dl>

</body>
</html>
```

So far I have this XSLT code that produces mostly correct Unix man page output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="html">
.TH "command" 1 "May 2015" "Package" "Organization"
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul">
.RS
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
.RE
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
.IP \(bu 4
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dl">
.P
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dt">
.TP
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dd">
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li/text()">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dd//text()">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only catch is that I want to also add a template for text nodes inside a `<dd>` node that immediately follow a `<ul>` node, which would look something like:

```
<xsl:template match="dd/text()[ ???? ]">
.IP
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that I can't figure out what to put inside the predicate (????) so that it matches only text nodes that immediately follow a `<ul>` as in the sample HTML code.  I suspect this is very simple, but many attempts and readings of the W3C XSLT definition document are not helping.

If it makes any difference, I'm using XSLT 2.0 and the Saxon 9 parser under Java which I run like this:

> java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform test.html test.xsl

Comment: "*I want to match a text node only if it follows a `<ul>` sibling node*" Follows, or immediately follows? Not the same thing.

Comment: You're right, what I want is "immediately follows", not just follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out what to put inside the predicate (????) so that it
>   matches only text nodes that immediately follow a `<ul>`

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="dd/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::ul]]">
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly!  That's quite a set of predicates.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `preceding-sibling::ul` predicate to match node that follow `<ul>` node within a common parent  :

```
dd/text()[preceding-sibling::ul]
```

Comment: This works, but also matches _any_ text nodes that follow a `<ul>`, where as I only want to match a text node if it immediately follows a `<ul>`.  I'll edit my question now to make that more clear.